# Why did the shoretrooper throw a grenade into cargo shuttle SW-0608?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, it is a shoretrooper that throws the grenade into cargo shuttle SW-0608.  Shouldn't he have recognized that ship as an Imperial vessel?

Comment: It seems to me the only odd thing is why the shoretrooper waited so long to throw the grenade.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Probably _because_ it was an Imperial shuttle.  One half of his brain is screaming "There are hostiles there, bomb it!" and the other half is saying "But you'll be responsible for destroying a *very expensive* piece of Imperial equipment!"

Comment: @DavidW Aye, I'll be more specific. I find it odd they took so long to kill Bodhi and then when they did they blew up the whole shuttle rather than just shooting him. Perhaps the implication is that they realised the shuttle was being used to get a signal to the Rebels but I haven't found anything official to back that theory up.

Answer (score 8):

It seems clear that the Rebels are defending the shuttle. Whether it was the means by which the Rebels came to Scarif or whether it was simply taken over in the initial assault, the fact that the Rebels don't want the Imperials to have it marks it as fairly obvious target when it comes to trapping them on the planet.

The Imperials on the ground are fighting a ground offensive while the walkers are tied up trying to shoot down their air support so the stormtroopers don't really have anything big enough to get through the shuttle's armour. When the opportunity comes for a stormtrooper to shove a *grenade* into the Rebel's shuttle, he (or possibly she) takes it without hesitation.

Note that even before this, they're not being especially careful about hitting the ship but aren't targeting the cable or the Master Console, which would suggest that they're still clueless about what Bodhi is up to.

> The stormtroopers were closing around the cargo shuttle. Bodhi could
>   tell because, not infrequently, a particle bolt would blaze up the
>   boarding ramp and impact the interior bulkhead, raining sparks onto
>   the floor. Bodhi didn’t know how many of Tonc’s people were still
>   alive, fighting desperately to hold their foes back; nor did he know
>   whether, at any moment, someone might sever the cable snaking up the
>   ramp to the communications console.